# Unity3d + GooglePlayPlugin Проблема?

Tags: unity3d

Привет !
У меня проблема которую я просто не знаю как исправить !
Я добавить в свой проект на Unity Плагин от Google Play.
При добавлений плагина или при компиляций игры проблем нету.
Проблема в том что когда я открываю мою игру на Эмуляторе ( Раньше все работало ) то ничего не происходит !! Вот мой скрипт которого я использую для проекта !

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я открываю игру  на эмуляторе то ни "Error" не появляется ни сцена не грузится. Просто ничего не происходит, пустой экран, жди хоть час ! В чем может быть проблема !? ниже я оставлю фото которые может быть вам что то подскажут !
Использую я Java 8 . Так как 9 не работает на Unity. Android последней версий. Unity 2017.1.1 . Ребята буду бесконечно благодарен если поможете ! СПАСИБО !
[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JskTy.png)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так а на эмуляторы гугловые сервисы установлены?

Comment: Гугл плей установлен !

Answer (score 0):

Поменял я скрипт вот в такую сторону ! Но это не дало результата !

```
public void Start()
{
    PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().Build();
    PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
    PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
    //
    Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) =>
    {
        if (success)
        {
            Application.LoadLevel(1);
        }
        else
        {
            Error.active = true;
        }
    });
}
```

}